# Red5 server installation on godaddy 64 BIT VPS server

Tags: java, server, vps, red5

I am using video wishper plugin it working perfectly on my local system. Now I am making my site live I had purchased vps server from godaddy but could not able to install red5 server. I am following this step https://www.qhoster.com/clients/knowledgebase/140/How-to-install-Red5-Media-Server-on-CentOS-VPS-and-Dedicated-Servers.html but one  url mention in step is dead now "http://red5.googlecode.com/svn/java/server/tags/1_0/ red5" then I tried other instruction but find java heap error when starting red5  this is link "muktware.io/setup-red5-streaming-media-server/ " other way to install red5 where I am getting heap error.

Let me know if any one know latest way to install red5 server or any suggestion get rid from this error "Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit."

Thanks in advance

Comment: Now I have installed red5 on server but when going to demo page and click on connect it's not connecting please check here and let me know http://50.62.134.23:5080/demos/BallControl.html

Comment: Finally It's installed on vps server